# True being input to function

Tags: ruby, syntax

When I run this program

```
def tng(x)
 tn =( x * (x+1) )/2
 return tn
end

i = 0 

while tng (i) <= 500
 i += 1
end

puts i
```

it gives me the error `` "undefined method `+' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)" ``. I suppose this means that `true` is input to the `tng(x)` function, but why would this occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby *spaces before parentheses* are significant. Parser treats

```
while tng (i) <= 500
```

as:

```
while tng((i) <= 500)
```

the latter is evaluated to `true` hence the error.

---

*Sidenote:* do not use `return` as a last statement in methods, it’s returned automatically. Also, don’t use `while` loops, use iterators [unless you do perfectly understand why a generic `loop` is to be used here]:

```
def tng(x)
 (x * (x + 1)) / 2
end

1.upto(Float::INFINITY).each do |i|
  break i unless tng(i) <= 500
end
```

Comment: Note that `1.step` returns an enumerator that can replace `upto(Float::INFINITY).each`. See [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step). (Upvoted earlier.)